# Listing files with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to bypass the use of a database table.

Is there away using php that I can create an array of a specific folder?

Basically what I am doing is a slide show so when I have the array I would like to be able to automatically create a foreach for each image but I need a way to pass the src/filename from the array.

Comment: Any general purpose programming language is going to be able to interact with the filesystem. You should know that much. So why not just go to the [PHP manual](http://php.net), and see that there's a whole section about [directory functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php)? Downvoted for official downvote reason #1: "this question does not show much research effort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You case use the [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

```
$files = glob("$path\*.");
foreach($files as $file) {
     //do something...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that easily with [scandir()](http://php.net/scandir)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php).

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is something that will give you an array containing the files in a folder, you can use this, found in the PHP documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php#104824

Note that it works recursively, so it will also give you all the files in subfolders.